# How do I add an interceptor to a typescript-axios client generated by an OpenAPI generator?

Tags: typescript, axios, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using the typescript-axios client generated by OpenAPI and I need to log the requests made by the client. I know how to use interceptors with axios, but how can I get at the underlying axios instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code generated by https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator has a protected `axios` property.

The following [partially quoted] block comes from an [`OpenAPITools/openapi-generator` issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11799#issuecomment-1153546079).

> The DefaultApi has a protected `axios` property which can be accessed
>
> ```
> const finnhubClient = new DefaultApi({
>   apiKey,
> })
>
> finnhubClient.axios.interceptors.response.use(
>   response => response,
>   error => {
>     console.log('error: ', error)
>     throw error
>   }
> )
> ```